# PHPBB Homepage integration?

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

I am working on my website and currently have a custom coded webpage and also phpbb running with it. I can't however seem to integrate phpbb into the homepage. I would like to have the info (number of members, posts etc) as well as a news section (recent posts/updates on the forum). I have done a deal of research on this but can't find a solution.  Anyone seen or know how to do an integration like this? Thanks a bunch, Josh.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect to your phpBB-database and select the things you want to know

for example I select a list of the newest post of special members (team members) in certain forums. The result is shown here: http://www.omega-day.com/?op=news&lang=0

For this I just wrote three views.

```
CREATE VIEW `teamuserfarben` AS select `u`.`username` AS `username`,`u`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,`g`.`group_colour` AS `group_colour` from ((`PREFIX_` `u` join `PREFIX_user_group` `ug` on((`u`.`user_id` = `ug`.`user_id`))) join `PREFIX_groups` `g` on((`ug`.`group_id` = `g`.`group_id`))) where (`g`.`group_id` in (<GROUP IDS>)) group by `u`.`username`;

CREATE VIEW `teammeldungen` AS select `u`.`username` AS `username`,`u`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,`t`.`forum_id` AS `forum_id`,`f`.`forum_name` AS `forum_name`,`t`.`topic_title` AS `topic_title`,`t`.`topic_id` AS `topic_id`,`p`.`post_id` AS `post_id`,`p`.`post_time` AS `post_time` from (((`PREFIX_` `u` join `PREFIX_posts` `p` on((`p`.`poster_id` = `u`.`user_id`))) join `PREFIX_topics` `t` on((`t`.`topic_id` = `p`.`topic_id`))) join `PREFIX_forums` `f` on((`f`.`forum_id` = `t`.`forum_id`))) where (`t`.`forum_id` in (<FORUM IDS TO WATCH>));

CREATE VIEW `teamallposts` AS select `tm`.`username` AS `username`,`tm`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,`tc`.`group_colour` AS `group_colour`,`tm`.`forum_id` AS `forum_id`,`tm`.`forum_name` AS `forum_name`,`tm`.`topic_title` AS `topic_title`,`tm`.`topic_id` AS `topic_id`,`tm`.`post_id` AS `post_id`,`tm`.`post_time` AS `post_time` from (`teammeldungen` `tm` left join `teamuserfarben` `tc` on((`tm`.`user_id` = `tc`.`user_id`))) order by `tm`.`post_id` desc;
```

So you can just work with the data of your phpBB like you want to. Search where the information you need is stored and select it. That's all!

Comment: how do I connect to the database on a different page? That is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: just the same way you connect to a local one, so you need server, username, password, database. And the remote server must allow your connect and give you the rights to query the data. but as you wrote in your question both pages are placed on the same server so that should not be a problem. If you ask yourself how to open two database connections, you cant at the same time. just close the one, open the second to get the data from the phpBB and close it afterworks to reopen the old one (if necessary).